# How much space does Raspbian use?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I can't find any info about how much space Raspbian uses.

I have checked the wikipedia article about it and the official FAQ.

Comment: Raspberry Pi questions _are on-topic for Super User_. See [discussion on meta.SU](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5976/why-was-question-about-the-space-required-for-installing-raspbian-closed-as-off). **Please do not vote to close this question again. It is perfectly OK for Super User.**

Comment: @Tyilo: [Raspberry Pi is now on-topic through community consensus](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5984/can-we-make-raspberry-pi-questions-off-topic-and-avoid-hurting-raspberry-pi-se).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          3.7G  1.6G  1.9G  46% /
```

Mine has a few packages added, but roughly around 1.6gb - which is why a [2gb card is recommended](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads) as a minimum.

Answer (score -1):

When i first got my pi, i had a bunch of books about how to get it up and running, and most of them said to get at LEAST a 1 Gb or 4 Gb sd card. a great way to get started with the pi is with the MAKE: Getting started with raspberry pi book.

[image: this is what one of the books looks like]

Comment: How does your answer improve upon the existing answer or provide more helpful information? Please be careful when answering older question that are already answer to make sure that you are actually adding value to the question. In this case, that is debatable.